# while running Rabbit mqqt getting error

Tags: rabbitmq

I have copied rabbit mqqt code from one article.

```
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
 import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

public class MqttPublishSample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String topic = "MQTT Examples";
    String content = "Message from MqttPublishSample";
    int qos = 0;
    String broker = "tcp://127.0.0.1:1883";
    String clientId = "pahomqttpublish1";

    try {
        MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId);
        MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connOpts.setUserName("guest");
        connOpts.setPassword("guest".toCharArray());
        connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
        System.out.println("Connecting to broker: " + broker);
        sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        System.out.println("Publishing message: " + content);
        MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
        message.setQos(qos);
        sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
        System.out.println("Message published");
        sampleClient.disconnect();
        System.out.println("Disconnected");
        System.exit(0);
    } catch (MqttException me) {
        System.out.println("reason " + me.getReasonCode());
        System.out.println("msg " + me.getMessage());
        System.out.println("loc " + me.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("cause " + me.getCause());
        System.out.println("excep " + me);
        me.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Getting error while running this code this not Qos issue 
error while connecting **sampleClient.connect(connOpts);**

**Error on console **

```
Connecting to broker: tcp://127.0.0.1:1883
reason 32109
msg Connection lost
loc Connection lost
cause java.io.EOFException
excep Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException
Connection lost (32109) - java.io.EOFException  atrg.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:146)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:267)   at rg.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:65) at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:107)
```

**Rabbitmq error log**

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Aug-2016::17:24:54 ===
** Generic server <0.469.0> terminating
** Last message in was 
{inet_async,#Port<0.12379>,4714,{ok,[16,42,0,4,77,81,84,84,4,194,0,60,0,16,112,97,104,111,109,113,116,116,112,117,98,108,105, 
             115,104,49,0,5,103,117,101,115,116,0,5,103,117,101,115,116]}}`
** When Server state == {state,#Port<0.12379>,"127.0.0.1:34033 -> 127.0.0.1:1883",true,running,false,none,{proc_state,#Port<0.12379>,
       {dict,0,16,16,8,80,48,{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]},{{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]}}},
                            {undefined,undefined},{0,nil},{0,nil},undefined,1,undefined,undefined,undefined,{undefined,undefined},undefined,<<"amq.topic">>}}
 Reason for termination ==
 {{badfun,none},[{rabbit_mqtt_frame,parse,2,[{file,"rabbitmq-mqtt/src/rabbit_mqtt_frame.erl"},{line,39}]},
 {rabbit_mqtt_reader,process_received_bytes,2,[{file,"rabbitmq-mqtt/src/rabbit_mqtt_reader.erl"},{line,136}]},{gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[{file,"src/gen_server2.erl"},{line,934}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}
```

Comment: I have the same error when I use mosquitto_pub command.

Comment: @mkudlacek check the ans it is working for me now

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed Rabitmq 3.2.5 through apt-get, please install new version of rabitmq 3.6.5 find here [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.6.5/rabbitmq-server_3.6.5-1_all.deb) then try